# What is the meaning of "dummy %k" at the end of Exec key in start-tor-browser.desktop file

Tags: .desktop, tor

I'm trying to understand how the start-tor-browser.desktop file works, especially the Exec key. Here it is:

```
Exec=sh -c '"$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach || ([ ! -x "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

I would like to know the role of the "dummy %k" at the end of the key.
I found on [this page](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables):
*%k is the location of the desktop file as either a URI (if for example gotten from the vfolder system) or a local filename or empty if no location is known.*
But nothing about **dummy**.

Comment: it´s the name of the script `$0` and `%k` will be is the first argument `$1`, example `sh -c 'echo name: $0, argument: $1' dummy %k`, It is used in, for example, error messages.

Comment: Thank's for your precise reply.